# Error displaying Highcharts chart in Firefox, IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, firefox, highcharts

Highcharts is displaying a chart perfectly in Chrome, but in Firefox, IE10, it returns the error:

> NS_ERROR_FAILURE: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]

This is the code I'm using:

```
$('#graf-1').highcharts({
        chart: {
            zoomType: 'xy'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Titel'
        },
        subtitle: {
            text: null
        },
        xAxis: [{
            categories: datax
        }],
        yAxis: [{ // Primary yAxis
            labels: {
                format: '{value:,.0f} €',
                style: {
                    color: cor1
                }
            },
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        }, { // Secondary yAxis
            title: {
                text: null //eixoz,
            },
            labels: {
                format: '{value} %',
                style: {
                    color: cor2
                }
            },
            opposite: true
        }],
        tooltip: {
            shared: true
        },
        legend: {
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'left',
            x: 120,
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            y: 100,
            floating: true,
            backgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },
        series: [{
            name: eixoz,
            color: cor2,
            type: 'line',
            yAxis: 1,
            data: dataz,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' %'
            },
            zIndex: 2
        }, {
            name: eixoy,
            color: cor1,
            type: 'column',
            data: datay,
            tooltip: {
                valueSuffix: ' €'
            },
            zIndex: 1
        }]
    });
```

Comment: Which HighCharts version do you use ?

Comment: Could you reproduce issue on jsFiddle?

Comment: @Zzirconium: I'm using v 3.0.7

Comment: I made a jsfiddle with your code (I added arbitrary data) and it works in firefox : http://jsfiddle.net/QurR6/1/

Comment: Yes, it works... I guess the problem isn't the chart then.

Comment: Only you know, there are many reasons possible to get such an error. All I can do is to let you play around in this fiddle to reproduce the error then come back to us. I am interested in the reason

Comment: I will let you know if I find out, it seems there is a confict with another library.